# Creating an OAuth2.0 sign in app using MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I need your help....
I need some code to get me started with an application I'm working.
I have a MVC5 app that will login users into the Planning Center and then redirect back to my website to perform some tasks. The problem at hand is that I'm having a hard time understanding how to authenticate users using the OAuth 2.0 specifications. Provided below are the details that the Planning Center requires in order for me to login and use their API:

1.Redirect the user’s browser to https://api.planningcenteronline.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://example.com/auth/complete&response_type=code&scope=peoplereplace CLIENT_ID and https://example.com/auth/complete with your actual redirect URI).If you need different scope, replace scope=people appropriately (see “Scopes” section below).

2.Planning Center will redirect the user’s browser back to the given redirect URI with a code param.

3.Send a POST request in the background to https://api.planningcenteronline.com/oauth/token with the following params:
{"grant_type": "authorization_code", "code": "CODE_FROM_STEP_2", "client_id": "CLIENT_ID", "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET", "redirect_uri": "https://example.com/auth/complete"}

(replace CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CODE_FROM_STEP_2, and the redirect URI appropriately).
curl -X POST https://api.planningcenteronline.com/oauth/token 
-F grant_type=authorization_code 
-F code=1234567890 
-F client_id=2345678901 
-F client_secret=3456789012 
-F redirect_uri=https://example.com/auth/complete

4. The response you get back will contain the access token and other information.
   {
   "access_token": "1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "expires_in": 7200,
   "refresh_token": "1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef",
   "scope": "people",
   "created_at": 1469553476
   }
5. Use the access token for all API requests by passing it in the Authorization header, using the Bearer authentication scheme.
   curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef' https://api.planningcenteronline.com/people/v2/people

For the full link to the documentation - https://developer.planning.center/docs/#/introduction/authentication

I just need to get started and I'm not sure where. Most of the examples out there are hard to understand and doesn't give enough details.

Any help would be appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the authorization code flow you need to make two requests in order to get a token back from the authorization server. The first one is made to the **authorize endpoint** where the user is asked to login. After successful login the client will get back a **code** from the authorization server, hence the name authorization code flow, to be used in the second request to the **token endpoint**. By sending a valid code, the server will send a response with the access token so you can access the protected resource with it.

You can get more information from the sequence diagram in the auth0 web site:
https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow

Comment: Thanks, do you have any code examples that get me started with sending handling the request from the successful login and then handing the post request? I thought this is something we can setup in the Startup.Auth.cs, but I don't understand how to use app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer or app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication

Comment: Sure! Take a look at this link: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/samples/csharp/get-token-and-users

Comment: Also take a look at this doc from bearer token: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/